# Let X be number of rolls till a 6, Y be the number of green balls sampled with replacement from an urn out of X balls sampled. Compute $P_{Y|X}(y|x)$

Tags: probability

Let X be number of rolls till a 6. Next we choose with replacement X balls from an urn with 5 red and 4 green, Y is defined as the number of green balls sampled.

Compute conditional PMF $P_{Y|X}(y|x)$
Compute E[Y|X]
Compute E[Y]

The prof didn't give us much to solve this just that $P_{X|Y}(x|y)=P(x,y)/p_Y(y)$, but it's hard to apply that to this cause X can be from 1 to infinity it seems(As it is probable but very very low chance of not rolling a 6 for a super large X). Also since it's asking for a PMF rather than a PDF it's not a continuous function, which I assumed it would be since X can range from 1 to infinity.

Comment: Are there any balls in the urn that aren't green?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add information regarding that.

Comment: I think this will help. https://www.math.arizona.edu/~tgk/464_07/cond_exp.pdf

Comment: this is nice, but an example of application would definitely be useful

Comment: What about the example in section A.2?  Why isn't that useful?

Comment: Sorry I meant an example that helps me find the conditional PMF for expectation that's certainly useful

Comment: I've got my answer corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me get you started on the probability mass function.  I'll just talk about the denominator, since you'll see how to do the numerator in the discussion.

First, note that $X$ can take any of the values, $1,2,3,\dots$.  This doesn't mean you will have a continuous random variable, because $X$ only takes discrete values.  The denominator is 
$$\Pr(Y=y)=\sum_{x=1}^\infty\Pr(X=x)\Pr(Y=y|X=x)$$

If $X=x$, we have $x-1$ rolls that are not $6$, followed by a $6$.  $$\Pr(X=x)=\left(\frac56\right)^{x-1}\frac16$$

For $\Pr(Y=y|X=x)$, we have ${x\choose y}$ ways to choose which $y$ balls are green, and the probability of drawing a green ball is $\frac49$.  That gives 
$$\Pr(Y=y|X=x)=\binom{x}{y}\left(\frac49\right)^y\left(\frac59\right)^{x-y}$$

Putting it together, I get $$\Pr(Y=y)=\frac15\left(\frac45\right)^y\sum_{x\geq y}^\infty{x\choose y}\left(\frac{25}{54}\right)^x$$ since ${x\choose y}=0$ when $x<y$.  Because $X$ cannot take the value $0$, $y=0$ is a special case.  We have $$\Pr(Y=0)=\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac16\left(\frac56\right)^{x-1}\left(\frac59\right)^x=\frac{5}{29}$$

To evaluate the sum when $y>0$, we write $n=x-y$ and get 
$$\begin{align}\sum_{x=y}^\infty\binom{x}{y}p^x&=
p^y\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{y+n}{y}p^n\\&=
p^y\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\binom{-y-1}{n}p^n\\
&=p^y(1-p)^{-y-1}\\
&=\left(\frac{25}{54}\right)^y\left(\frac{54}{29}\right)^{y+1}\\
&=\frac{54}{29}\left(\frac{25}{29}\right)^y
\end{align}$$

Putting this together with the previous result gives $$\Pr(Y=y)=\frac{54}{145}\left(\frac{20}{29}\right)^y\text{ when } y>0$$

As a sanity check, $$\sum_{y=0}^\infty\Pr(Y=y) = \frac{5}{29}+\frac{54}{145}\sum_{y=1}^\infty\left(\frac{20}{29}\right)^y=1$$

Comment: I'm getting a function you can't integrate for E[Y|X]. I got $E[Y|X]=\int_0^{\infty} xf_{Y|X}(y,x)dx=\sum_0^{\infty} {x \choose y} \frac{4}{9}^y \frac{5}{9}^{x-y}$

Comment: Shouldn't you be multiplying by $y$ instead of $x$?  Also, I don't see how you got the sum, or why you think it can't be evaluated.  You really should ask a new question, showing what you've done, and where you're having trouble.

Comment: Sorry you're right that should be a  y.

Comment: And $dy$ instead of $dx$